# Apple Sign In DisplayName not being returned using Flutter and Firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, sign-in-with-apple

I know there's been a few reports about this, but I'm trying to get the DisplayName retrieved when signing in using Apple SignIn.

Here's the code, it will print the DisplayName correctly in the console, but it still won't update the users record with the DisplayName. The sign in otherwise works correctly.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:crypto/crypto.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sign_in_with_apple/sign_in_with_apple.dart';

import 'auth_util.dart';

/// Generates a cryptographically secure random nonce, to be included in a
/// credential request.
String generateNonce([int length = 32]) {
  final charset =
      '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-._';
  final random = Random.secure();
  return List.generate(length, (_) => charset[random.nextInt(charset.length)])
      .join();
}

/// Returns the sha256 hash of [input] in hex notation.
String sha256ofString(String input) {
  final bytes = utf8.encode(input);
  final digest = sha256.convert(bytes);
  return digest.toString();
}

Future<UserCredential> appleSignIn() async {
  if (kIsWeb) {
    final provider = OAuthProvider("apple.com")
      ..addScope('email')
      ..addScope('fullName');

    // Sign in the user with Firebase.
    return await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithPopup(provider);
  }
  // To prevent replay attacks with the credential returned from Apple, we
  // include a nonce in the credential request. When signing in in with
  // Firebase, the nonce in the id token returned by Apple, is expected to
  // match the sha256 hash of `rawNonce`.
  final rawNonce = generateNonce();
  final nonce = sha256ofString(rawNonce);

  // Request credential for the currently signed in Apple account.
  final appleCredential = await SignInWithApple.getAppleIDCredential(
    scopes: [
      AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.email,
      AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.fullName,
    ],
    nonce: nonce,
  );

  // Create an `OAuthCredential` from the credential returned by Apple.
  final oauthCredential = OAuthProvider("apple.com").credential(
    idToken: appleCredential.identityToken,
    rawNonce: rawNonce,
  );

  final fixDisplayNameFromApple = [
    appleCredential.givenName ?? '',
    appleCredential.familyName ?? '',
  ].join(' ').trim();

  print(fixDisplayNameFromApple);

  // Sign in the user with Firebase. If the nonce we generated earlier does
  // not match the nonce in `appleCredential.identityToken`, sign in will fail.
  final userCredential =
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(oauthCredential);

  final firebaseUser = userCredential.user;
  if (firebaseUser!.displayName == null)
    await firebaseUser.updateDisplayName(fixDisplayNameFromApple);
  firebaseUser.reload();

  return userCredential;
}

Future<User?> signInWithApple(BuildContext context) =>
    signInOrCreateAccount(context, appleSignIn, 'APPLE');
```